# Where can I find "A Course of Lessons in Spoken Mandarin" ( 《华英联珠分类集成》)?

Tags: resources

孔夫子旧书网 is selling ["A Course of Lessons in Spoken Mandarin" ( 《华英联珠分类集成》)](http://book.kongfz.com/10795/621624155/) for 13000.00元.

I'm not sure who has that kind of dough to drop on a book, but it's certainly not me.

Some have used it to write papers:

- 文焕章《华英联珠分类集成》分析
- 传教士西南官话文献的罗马字拼音方案府

This is usually the sort of material that can be found on [archive.org](https://archive.org/), but, alas, it isn't there.

Apparently it is in the [Toronto Public Library](http://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM662707&R=662707) and [SOAS University of London](https://library.soas.ac.uk/Record/557004).

Is there a digital version available that is somehow eluding me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the up vote, got me back into looking for this and I found it:

[《华英联珠分类集成》/ pdf](http://202.115.54.114/huaxi110/sites/default/files/2020-03/11419152.pdf), for anyone looking for it.