# Why is 饰界 used to mean "hinges" in a 1908 book?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've got this translation here:

> [image]

> 13. The door turns on its hinges.

> [image]

> 13. 门靠着饰界转

I'm assuming 饰界 matches up with hinges. It's not a word I've encountered before or that's readily searchable online. The translation is old; 1908. The book also looks topolectical; Southwestern Mandarin.

It's looking unverifiable for me at the moment.

Ideas?

Comment: https://shopee.tw/超爆-超好看密封條露超4寸不銹鋼平開合頁靜音軸承門活頁木門大門房門折頁合葉鉸鏈飾界風貨源-i.26494793.2705822744 - there are more than 5 words for "door hinge" that this seller has put up. 飾界 is one of them, but you also see the common 鉸鏈, and others like 合頁, 合葉, silent pivot 靜音軸, the dialectical spelling 活頁

Comment: Interesting. I wonder where the usage originated from.

Comment: Uhh..maybe that wasn't quite right. 飾界風 might mean something else. Anyway, you're right, this is very hard to find, we don't have anybody speaking 成都話 here?

Comment: From Qing? Probably not. It doesn't look like something any modern person would know.

Comment: I think the character choice, especially for the first syllable, might be a phonetic loan, so this is some sort of ad-hoc transliteration into characters. This is why it might be close to impossible to find, there might be a more common character representation that we don't know of.

Comment: 活页 shows up in multiple Southwestern Mandarin resources as "(名) 铰链。" but I'm not seeing any other references to any sort of hinge. I would assume people would opt for something more colloquial than professional as well.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the book? Looks interesting.

Comment: @Stan https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/23132/4136

Comment: @Stan pdf: http://202.115.54.114/huaxi110/sites/default/files/2020-03/11419152.pdf p9-10, for the English & Chinese posted above.

Answer (score 2):

It means "hinge" in old Chengdu dialect.

The source is the same the one I mentioned [in the other post](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39893/12003), a 2006 research thesis from Waseda University Graduate School of Letters:

[成都方言の文法研究 A study of Chengdu dialect grammar](https://waseda.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=2685&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=21)

The third file "Honbun-4423.pdf" from this download page is the paper I'm referring to.

Same as in the other post, in Appendix 4 you can see the following footnote in Japanese:

> 括弧内の文は現代成都方言の言い方である
>
> The statements between brackets are in the modern Chengdu dialect

The at page 236 you can find an exact match of your example number 13 you posted here.

> 13． 門靠着飾界轉 （門靠倒飾界轉）
>
> Men2 kao4 dzo2 si4 jien4 dzuan3

Between brackets, the modern version.

Comment: The original source in the question clearly indicated 飾界 meant hinge. I guess OP need other sources to cross-verify the fact. The source in this answer was good but it just adopted the explanation of the original book without citing others -- so the doubt whether the original source was correct, whether that "hinge" looked like the modern hinge, was not solved yet.