# 車轉 as "door knob"?

Tags: meaning

This a a bit of a follow up to [饰界 for "hinges"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/39686/4136)

---

I've got this translation here:

> [image]

> 9. Takes hold of the knob.
> 10. Gives the knob a turn.

> [image]

> 9. 把車轉拿着
> 10. 把車轉扭一下

I'm assuming 車轉 matches up with knob here. It's not a word I've encountered before or that's readily searchable online. The translation is old; 1908. The book also looks topolectical; Southwestern Mandarin.

It's looking unverifiable for me at the moment.

Ideas?

Comment: Well this word makes more sense than 飾界. It looks like 車 in Southwestern Mandarin means 轉, while 轉 in Southwestern Mandarin means 回. 把車轉拿着 = take a hold of that [thing which rotates one way then rotates back].

Answer (score 1):

It means "knob" in old Chengdu dialect.

The single source I was able to fish up is what looks like a 2006 research thesis from Waseda University Graduate School of Letters:

[成都方言の文法研究 A study of Chengdu dialect grammar](https://waseda.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=2685&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=21)

The third file "Honbun-4423.pdf" from this download page contains the paper I'm referring to. The Appendix 4 is:

> 《華英聯珠分類集成》（ 第一課～第十九課）

Which is probably the text where you found this word in the first place. (I'm guessing based on [this other post of yours](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23132/where-can-i-find-a-course-of-lessons-in-spoken-mandarin-%E5%8D%8E%E8%8B%B1%E8%81%94%E7%8F%A0%E5%88%86%E7%B1%BB%E9%9B%86%E6%88%90))

The title of Appendix 4 is then accompanied by this footnote in Japanese:

> 括弧内の文は現代成都方言の言い方である
>
> The statements between brackets are in the modern Chengdu dialect

Which seems to corroborate my assumptions, and the nature of this paper.

At page 235 you can find exactly the two examples number 9 and 10 that you posted here, along with their corresponding modern version.

> 9． 把車轉拿着（把把手拿倒）
>
> Ba3 tse1 dzuan4 na2 dzo2

> 10． 把車轉扭一下 （把把手扭了 no2 一下）
>
> Ba3 tse1 dzuan4 gniou3 i2 ha4

Comment: This feels a bit circular, though. The Waseda thesis is getting their reference from《華珠》to begin with, no?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I thought this could be construed as additional evidence of the origin of the term, including some more precise indication of which language/dialect it comes from.

Comment: @Mo. otherwise, I might have misunderstood what you're looking for

Comment: It's a good answer but I'm assuming that Xiong Jin was just reconstructing it the same way I did.